Input serialization in Durable Function with Orchestrator
Using .NET 8 and azure functions in isolated mode, I have an EventGridTrigger function that starts up an orchestrator while providing a typed input as parameter. The parameter's type is part of the following class hierarchy:
[JsonDerivedType(typeof(IntegrationEventBase), typeDiscriminator: "IntegrationEventBase")]
[JsonDerivedType(typeof(WorkItemIntegrationEventBase), typeDiscriminator: "WorkItemIntegrationEventBase")]
public class IntegrationEventBase
{
    public string? Traceparent { get; set; }
}

[JsonDerivedType(typeof(WorkItemCreatedIntegrationEvent), typeDiscriminator: "WorkItemCreatedIntegrationEvent")]
[JsonDerivedType(typeof(WorkItemProgressedIntegrationEvent), typeDiscriminator: "WorkItemProgressedIntegrationEvent")]
public class WorkItemIntegrationEventBase : IntegrationEventBase
{
    public string? WorkItemId { get; set; }

    public ushort? Quantity { get; set; }
}

public class WorkItemCreatedIntegrationEvent : WorkItemIntegrationEventBase
{
}

public class WorkItemProgressedIntegrationEvent : WorkItemIntegrationEventBase
{
    public WorkItemStatus Status { get; set; }
}

The EventGridTrigger function
This is simply deserializing the event received from Event Grid and passing it as the input of the orchestrator
[Function("WorkItemProgressedIntegrationEventHandler")]
public async Task WorkItemProgressedIntegrationEventHandler([EventGridTrigger] EventGridEvent eventGridEvent,
    [DurableClient] DurableTaskClient client,
    FunctionContext executionContex)
{
    var @event = _serializer.Deserialize<WorkItemProgressedIntegrationEvent>(eventGridEvent.Data.ToString());

    await client.ScheduleNewOrchestrationInstanceAsync(
        Constants.WORKFLOW_ORCHESTRATOR, @event);
}

The Orchestrator
The orchestrator receives a WorkItemIntegrationEventBase and then it will call the entity in one of two different ways based on the actual inner type of the event (polymorphism).
[Function("Orchestrator")]
public static async Task RunOrchestrator(
    [OrchestrationTrigger] TaskOrchestrationContext context, WorkItemIntegrationEventBase @event)
{
    var entityId = BuildEntityIds(@event);

    if (@event is WorkItemCreatedIntegrationEvent createdEvent)
        await context.Entities.SignalEntityAsync(workflowEntityId, nameof(IDurableWorkflow.EnqueueWork),
            WorkItemInput.FromWorkItemIntegrationEvent(createdEvent));
    else if (@event is WorkItemProgressedIntegrationEvent progressedEvent)
        await context.Entities.SignalEntityAsync(workflowEntityId, nameof(IDurableWorkflow.ProgressWork),
            WorkItemInput.FromWorkItemIntegrationEvent(progressedEvent));
}

Issue!: I can't get the @event in the orchestrator to deserialize using the type information of the type that was used in the event trigger meaning that both of the checks above are always false.
I have tried almost everything stated here but no luck, I must be missing something still.

Can you share your repo?

This worked for me.
I used a simple data and I added logger to print the values of if else.
If you are passing the event value to orchestration you need to use in this syntax
input:@event

string instanceId = await client.ScheduleNewOrchestrationInstanceAsync(
                nameof(Function1),input:@event);

My code:
Function1.cs:
using Azure.Messaging;
using Azure.Messaging.EventGrid;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Http;
using Microsoft.DurableTask;
using Microsoft.DurableTask.Client;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using System.Text.Json;
using System.Text.Json.Serialization;

namespace FunctionApp3
{
    public static class Function1
    {

        [Function(nameof(Function1))]
        public static async Task RunOrchestrator(
            [OrchestrationTrigger] TaskOrchestrationContext context, WorkItemIntegrationEventBase @event)
        {
            var entity = @event;

            ILogger logger = context.CreateReplaySafeLogger(nameof(Function1));
            logger.LogInformation($"Saying hello. \nValues are: \n \t{entity.WorkItemId} \n \t{entity.Quantity}");

            if (@event is WorkItemCreatedIntegrationEvent cloudEvent)
            {
                logger.LogInformation("it is a WorkItemCreatedIntegrationEvent");
            }
            else
            {
                logger.LogInformation("it is a WorkItemProgressedIntegrationEvent");
            }

        [Function("EventGrid")]
        public static async Task Run([EventGridTrigger] EventGridEvent cloudEvent,
            [DurableClient] DurableTaskClient client,
            FunctionContext executionContext)
        {
            ILogger logger = executionContext.GetLogger("Function1_HttpStart");

            var @event = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<WorkItemProgressedIntegrationEvent>(cloudEvent.Data.ToString());

            
            string instanceId = await client.ScheduleNewOrchestrationInstanceAsync(
                nameof(Function1),input:@event);

            logger.LogInformation("Started orchestration with ID = '{instanceId}'.", instanceId);
        }
    }

    [JsonDerivedType(typeof(IntegrationEventBase), typeDiscriminator: "IntegrationEventBase")]
    [JsonDerivedType(typeof(WorkItemIntegrationEventBase), typeDiscriminator: "WorkItemIntegrationEventBase")]
    public class IntegrationEventBase
    {
        public string? Traceparent { get; set; }
    }

    [JsonDerivedType(typeof(WorkItemCreatedIntegrationEvent), typeDiscriminator: "WorkItemCreatedIntegrationEvent")]
    [JsonDerivedType(typeof(WorkItemProgressedIntegrationEvent), typeDiscriminator: "WorkItemProgressedIntegrationEvent")]
    public class WorkItemIntegrationEventBase : IntegrationEventBase
    {
        public string? WorkItemId { get; set; }

        public string? Quantity { get; set; }
    }

    public class WorkItemCreatedIntegrationEvent : WorkItemIntegrationEventBase
    {
    }

    public class WorkItemProgressedIntegrationEvent : WorkItemIntegrationEventBase
    {
        public WorkItemStatus Status { get; set; }
    }

    public enum WorkItemStatus
    {
        InProgress,
        Completed
    }
}

Program.cs:
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

var host = new HostBuilder()
    .ConfigureFunctionsWebApplication()
    .ConfigureServices(services =>
    {
        services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetryWorkerService();
        services.ConfigureFunctionsApplicationInsights();
    })
    .ConfigureLogging(logging =>
    {
        logging.Services.Configure<LoggerFilterOptions>(options =>
        {
            LoggerFilterRule defaultRule = options.Rules.FirstOrDefault(rule => rule.ProviderName
                == "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ApplicationInsights.ApplicationInsightsLoggerProvider");
            if (defaultRule is not null)
            {
                options.Rules.Remove(defaultRule);
            }
        });
    })
    .Build();

host.Run();

INPUT:
EventGrid Schema sample
[
    {
        "id":"test-id",
        "data":{"WorkItemId": "value1", "Quantity": "value2"},
        "subject":"test-subject",
        "eventType":"test-event-1",
        "eventTime":"2024-11-3",
        "dataVersion":"1.0"
    }
]


OUTPUT:

EDIT:
It is not triggering none is because the type of @event not belongs to any of them.
I tried getting type of @event using @event.GetType(). The value is Type of @event is: FunctionApp3.WorkItemIntegrationEventBase
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Http;
using Microsoft.DurableTask;
using Microsoft.DurableTask.Client;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using System.Text.Json;
using System.Text.Json.Serialization;

namespace FunctionApp3
{
    public static class Function1

    {

        [Function(nameof(Function1))]
        public static async Task RunOrchestrator(
            [OrchestrationTrigger] TaskOrchestrationContext context, WorkItemIntegrationEventBase @event)
        {
            var entity = @event;

            ILogger logger = context.CreateReplaySafeLogger(nameof(Function1));
            logger.LogInformation($"Saying hello. \nValues are: \n \t{entity.WorkItemId} \n \t{entity.Quantity}");

            logger.LogInformation($"Type of @event is: {@event.GetType()}");

            if (@event is WorkItemCreatedIntegrationEvent)
            {
                logger.LogInformation("it is a WorkItemCreatedIntegrationEvent");
            }
            else if(@event is WorkItemProgressedIntegrationEvent)
            {
                logger.LogInformation("it is a WorkItemProgressedIntegrationEvent");

            }
            else
            {
                logger.LogInformation("it was Neither");
            }

        }


        [Function("EventGrid")]
        public static async Task Run([EventGridTrigger] Azure.Messaging.EventGrid.EventGridEvent cloudEvent,
            [DurableClient] DurableTaskClient client,
            FunctionContext executionContext)
        {
            ILogger logger = executionContext.GetLogger("EventGrid");

            var @event = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<WorkItemIntegrationEventBase>(cloudEvent.Data.ToString());


            string instanceId = await client.ScheduleNewOrchestrationInstanceAsync(
                nameof(Function1), input: @event);

            logger.LogInformation("Started orchestration with ID = '{instanceId}'.", instanceId);
        }
    }

        [JsonDerivedType(typeof(IntegrationEventBase), typeDiscriminator: "IntegrationEventBase")]
        [JsonDerivedType(typeof(WorkItemIntegrationEventBase), typeDiscriminator: "WorkItemIntegrationEventBase")]
        public class IntegrationEventBase
        {
            public string? Traceparent { get; set; }
        }

        [JsonDerivedType(typeof(WorkItemCreatedIntegrationEvent), typeDiscriminator: "WorkItemCreatedIntegrationEvent")]
        [JsonDerivedType(typeof(WorkItemProgressedIntegrationEvent), typeDiscriminator: "WorkItemProgressedIntegrationEvent")]
        public class WorkItemIntegrationEventBase : IntegrationEventBase
        {
            [JsonPropertyName("Type")]
            public string? Type { get; set; }
            public string? WorkItemId { get; set; }

            public string? Quantity { get; set; }
        }

        public class WorkItemCreatedIntegrationEvent : WorkItemIntegrationEventBase
        {
        }

        public class WorkItemProgressedIntegrationEvent : WorkItemIntegrationEventBase
        {
            public WorkItemStatus Status { get; set; }
        }

        public enum WorkItemStatus
        {
            InProgress,
            Completed
        }
    }



Hey Vivek, thanks for the answer but it seems like you missed an important piece of my code hence why it seems like it is working on your end when in reality it is not. In the orchestrator I provided my code with an if {} else if {} block to explicitly check for both events. You are only checking explicitly against WorkItemCreatedIntegrationEvent but then you have an else which would cover any other case.
If you check explicitly you will see that both validations are still false

@FelipeCorrea I will update my answer as per your suggestion
